# Replace button by div for modify

Tags: angularjs

I got a new question for you.

I have 2

First one is in case when their are no description : it's a button.
On click that show an textarea for write the description.

Second one is in case when their are a description, that show the field and modify input.

And I got a button for apply.

I did that with

```
<div ng-show = "description != ''">{{Description}}</div>

<div ng-show = "description == ''">
    <textarea></textarea>
</div>
```

My problem is when I write the first character inside of my textarea, the input disapear and my description appears, and i can't write anything else before to apply my description.

Can I fix it so that the ng-show work when I press my apply button ?

Keep in mind, i'm begginer with angular. Don't judge me :p

Thanks guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guessing that you have an `ng-model` somewhere, you can use `ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur' }"`, meaning the value will be updated when you leave the textarea, and not while you're typing.

Answer (score 0):

you should maintain 2 divs. 1st div is enable for true and 2nd div as false after clickable event you enable 2nd div as true and 1st div as false.